# Django and AJAX form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a django modelform that I have setup to use jQuery and the jQuery AjaxForm plugin.

It quite correctly processes any data submitted and either shows errors or saves, however it simply will not repopulate the form with refreshed data post successful submit.

Here is my code:

```
@login_required
@transaction.commit_on_success
def edit(request, pk):
    a = get_object_or_404(Item.objects.select_related(), pk=pk)
    b = Status.objects.all() # was select_related()
    currentsec = a.integrity_hash
    item_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Item).id

    try:
        last_viewed = request.session['last_viewed']
        if pk not in last_viewed:
                if len(last_viewed) > 19:
                        last_viewed.pop(0)        
                last_viewed.append(pk)
        request.session['last_viewed'] = last_viewed
    except KeyError:
        request.session['last_viewed'] = [pk]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = ItemForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        if f.is_valid():
            editted_item = f.save(commit=False)
            # check for changes to item before save
            if currentsec == editted_item.integrity_hash:
                editted_item.integrity_hash = form_hmac(f)
                # lock item row for updating
                Item.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=pk)
                editted_item.save()

                m = Modification.objects.create(
                    content_object = a,
                    object_id = pk,
                    action = 1,
                    modifier = request.user,
                    )
                m.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Item editted successfully.')

                if request.is_ajax():
                    response_dict = serialize('json', (editted_item,))
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit', kwargs={'pk': pk,}))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Item could not be saved. It has been modified whilst you were working on it.')
                response_dict = json.dumps({'errors': dict([(k, [unicode(e) for e in v]) for k,v in f.errors.items()])})
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Item could not be saved.')
            response_dict = json.dumps({'errors': dict([(k, [unicode(e) for e in v]) for k,v in f.errors.items()])})
    else:
        f = ItemForm(instance=a)
        f.fields["item_maker"].queryset = ItemMaker.objects.filter(Q(end_date__isnull=True) | Q(pk = a.item_maker.id) | Q(end_date__gte=a.date_due))

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'item': a,
        'form': f,
        'itemstatus': b,
        'item_ct': item_ct,
    })

    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(response_dict, mimetype="application/json")

    return render_to_response('items/item_edit.html', variables)
```

Comment: There is lot going on i dont understand - why do you need to redirect after successful save? If you post to same page then you dont really need to redirect after save. Just return same template with already existing context object and form will have exactly the same data you posted. Also, since your view handles ajax requests differently - your question does not show if its the problem of ajax request or regular request. If its in case of ajax you should show what does ajax return and how your webpage handles it. and another note - you could just add save method to form to handle hash update.